# Multiple people using mod flag

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

Today I came across a suspicious looking answer and I asked what I should do with it in a chatroom. Another user said he already flagged it for moderator attention. I got the suggestion to also flag it but it was unclear if that would actually be helpful.

My question is: Are multiple flags for moderator attention on a post useful or actually counter productive?

Comment: at best they put a post higher in the mod queue but if there is a lurking puppy in the chat room I wouldn't bother to cast extra flags.

Comment: @rene You mean the [ninja puppy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, they can be useful. The more flags a post has on it, the higher it is sorted in the moderator flag queue. If something really needs to be acted on right now, that's one way to make sure it comes to our attention.

Additional custom flags can also point out things that others missed. Someone might flag that a poster is rolling back edits, but someone else might point out that they were also being abusive in comments. That additional context can help with how we handle a post.

We have the ability to accept or decline individual flags on the same post, so even if someone casts a bad flag you won't end up being punished for it.

Just make sure you're doing this with the intention to help, and not just to farm helpful flags by piling on. That isn't so much of a problem now, but it used to be one back in the day when certain flags were exposed to 10k users.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211728/how-did-this-answer-manage-to-garner-50-incorrect-not-an-answer-flags-in-less